# PHP multiple records insert

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables, insert

I am attempting to reword my issue.

I have a datatable that can return thousands of records, each with multiple columns. There is a checkbox in the first column that, once the user checks it, they then click a button, and the CONTAINER_NUMBER that is associated with the row is sent to a modal window to be used in a form.

Here is the code for the checkbox:

```
 echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$Row[CONTAINER_NUMBER]}\" name=\"checkMr[]\" /></td>";
```

This is the javascript that retrieves the CONTAINER_NUMBER and sends it to the modal window:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function()
   {
    $('a').click(function()
    {
        var selectedID = [];
        $(':checkbox[name="checkMr[]"]:checked').each(function()
        {               
            selectedID.push($(this).attr('id'))         
        });                                             
        $(".modal-body .containerNumber").val( selectedID );
       });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the section of the modal window that displays the CONTAINER_NUMBER:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
   <form action="" method="POST" id="serviceModalForm" name="serviceModalForm">
   <input type="text" name="containerNumber" id="containerNumber" class="containerNumber">
```

Here is the section of PHP that takes the id="containerNumber" and converts it to a PHP variable. After that, there is an INSERT statement that inserts the containerNumber into a database table:

```
 <?php
   $container = $_POST['containerNumber'];

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $container = mysql_real_escapse_string(stripslashes($container));

     $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (container_num) VALUES ('$container')";

     if(mysql_query($sql)){
       echo "Insert complete";
     }
     else {
       echo "Insert was not completed";
     }
 ?>
```

This code is fine.  It works good.  It does what it's supposed to do...for when the user checks ONE checkbox.  It DOES NOT work when the user checks multiple checkboxes.

Basically, from what I've been researching is that I need to separate the records from the variable $container, as there can be multiple containers in that variable, which is why the query does not work when there are more than one container numbers selected.

I need to be able to separate the container numbers and store them in an array or something. The query will read each record separately and generate multiple INSERT statements for each record.

I've tried several times to create an array and get the sql statement to recognize it, but have been unsuccessful.  I'm not sure if I'm placing the array in the right place.  I'm not sure if this has to be done in the javascript before the container gets sent to the modal window.

I know I need to utilize a FOREACH loop to go through the array, but like I said, I'm not sure where the array needs to go in my code.

Please help.  I know I need to learn PDO or MYSQLI.  I will be sure to utilize PDO or MYSQLI on my next application.  Until then, please help me with this issue.

Thank you, and sorry for so much wording.

Comment: Please post your HTML form as it is output in the browser. And also post the content of `$_POST['containerNumber']`. That would help clarify the issue for me.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking me to do. To summarize, in the PHP code, $container could have multiple container numbers assigned to it. So currently, the insert statement is looking at $container as a string or something. Like this: $container = ct1, ct2, ct3... There should be multiple insert per each record assigned to $container. I hope I'm wording that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your containerNumber will be posted as a converted string from a js array. Something like id1, id2, id3[...]

In your php code, convert the $container back to an array (`$containerArray = explode(",", $container)`) and construct the sql dynamically to add all the rows in a single query so that the statment becomes something like

```
INSERT INTO myTable (container_num) VALUES ('$containerArray[0]'), ('$containerArray[1]')[...]
```